# eval for filtering values containing search in multidimensional array

Tags: php, eval

I was trying to create a function for filtering LIKE values in multiple columns of multidimensional array. I tried to loop through the array of column names to create a strpos function but in string format. When I used eval to run the imploded string of code, I received error "Unexpected end of file, eval d'code on line xx".

I don't understand the problem. Here is the function:

```
public function ArrayFilterLike($array, $filter, $search){
    $result = [];
    foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
        $filter[$key] = "strpos(\$data['$value'], \$search) !== false";
    }

    $filter = implode(" || ", $filter);

    foreach ($array as $data) {
        if(eval($filter)){
            $result[] = $data;
        }
    }

    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: i see no reason to use eval  here.

Comment: Remove the quotes around the value of `$filter`, remove eval, and you'll be set.

Comment: I can't make the imploded strpos function to work. Can someone show me the actual solution? Will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ArrayFilterLike($array, $filter, $search){
    $result = [];
    foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
        $filter[$key] = "strpos(\$data['$value'], \$search) !== false";
    }

    $filter = implode(" || ", $filter);

    foreach ($array as $data) {
        if(eval("return $filter;")){
            $result[] = $data;
        }
    }

    print_r($result);
}
```

Got it done. Thanks.

Comment: please read the manuals warning about eval(), its not needed here at all